# Group by week, display empty weeks - with where clause

Tags: mysql, join

We are attempting to count how many unique telephone numbers called a particular number each day, with 0 (or NULL) for days with no calls. To simplify the data schema, our table contains four fields:

```
    | id | fromz | toz | date |

    fromz: inbound call number
    toz: number called
    date: yyyy-mm-dd
```

When all we need to know is how many unique numbers called by each day - and do not care what number was called - it is simple to include no-calls days in results.

We JOIN to another table containing only sequential dates: calendar

```
    | id | date |

    date:yyyy-mm-dd

    SELECT p.fromz, count(unique(p.fromz)), p.date FROM phones p
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendar c ON
    p.date = c.date
    GROUP BY c.date
```

If no p.fromz on c.date, the result for that p.date is "0" (or NULL)

Problem arises when we begin to sort by numbers called:

```
    SELECT p.fromz, count(unique(p.fromz)), p.date FROM phones p
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendar ON
    p.date = c.date
    WHERE p.toz = "@myNumber"
    GROUP BY c.date
```

Because there are no WHERE toz = @myNumber on some days we only get results on days when (WHERE) there were calls to @myNumber.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does your question header mention "group by week?" It looks to me like you're grouping by days.

Comment: My bad. Can be grouped by any period of time (second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year) but I didn't revise the heading to reflect the simplified form of the question.

Grouping by week or month introduces another set of complexities that are well answered elsewhere -- i.e. GROUP BY WEEK(c.date,3) returns weeks of year, not rolling 7-day periods across calendar years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified some of your field names slightly. I'm not sure if this 100% meets your use-case, but if it doesn't, you should be able to figure it out from here. Basically, move your current `WHERE` condition into the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT p.fromz, count(distinct p.fromz), p.callDate, c.theDate FROM phones p
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendar c ON
    p.callDate = c.theDate AND p.toz = 2125555555
    GROUP BY c.theDate
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c347/5)

**Full Disclosure**
This is not standards-compliant. For a compliant query, take a look at Ollie's answer and simply move the `p.toz` part from the `WHERE` to the `ON` to get the results you want.

Comment: That is generally the solution that worked. SELECT p.fromz is extraneous because we are counting aggregated distinct(p.fromz).

p.callDate is not required in the SELECT statement, unless required for compliant syntax.

Calendar table is longer than required for report, so 
       WHERE c.theDate BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD' and 'YYYY-MM-DD' statement limits results.

Comment: @zyghi I'm not exactly sure what the point of your comment is. Your question didn't specify exactly what fields you wanted returned and did not indicate that you wanted the result limited by a date range. If one of the two current answers provided the correct results according to your original question, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: The point of my comment was to add commentary indicating what other changes I made in the query as posted. Since "These rules specify that each column mentioned in the SELECT clause must be either (1) also mentioned in the GROUP BY clause" I considered somebody might care whether a field was necessary in the SELECT clause.

Upon reading your helpful comment, I rexamined my response to my initial effort to "Vote up" the answer that told me I am not popular enough to vote. I clicked on outline of an upside down chevron and concluded that must be the "choose this as the correct answer" icon.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

You're using a nasty MySQL nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY` and it is driving you crazy, as it has driven many others crazy before you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

You need to follow the rules for standard `GROUP BY`. These rules specify that each column mentioned in the SELECT clause must be either (1) also mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause or (2) an aggregate function.

There are two problems in your query.  One is that you mention `p.date` instead of `c.date` in your `SELECT` clause.  That `p.date` will be null if there aren't any items on the date in question in your `phones` table.  The second item is that you're mentioning p.fromz twice.

I think your basic aggregate query should look like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef4e/3/0:

```
SELECT p.toz, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.fromz) AS unique_calling_number_count, 
       c.date 
  FROM phones AS p
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendar AS c ON p.date = c.date
 GROUP BY p.toz, c.date 
 ORDER BY c.date, p.toz
```

That will summarize call-origination numbers by day and call-destination numbers.

Then, when you need to filter your `phones` records according to some kind of criterion, do that in a subquery as follows.

```
SELECT p.toz, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.fromz) AS unique_calling_number_count, 
       c.date 
  FROM (
         SELECT *    /* filtering subquery */
           FROM phones
          WHERE toz = "@myNumber"
       )  AS p
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN calendar AS c ON p.date = c.date
 WHERE p.toz = "@myNumber"
 GROUP BY p.toz, c.date 
 ORDER BY c.date, p.toz
```

Here's an example of this working.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef4e/2/0  Thanks to @PatrickQ for noticing the WHERE at the wrong level of the query.

Comment: Hey Ollie. Spot-on in terms of standards. I'll admit that I violate that rule a lot. However, your second query doesn't quite seem to produce the requested results when running it against my (very small) sample set. [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c347/7). I believe the OP wants to see counts of 0 on days when there were no calls.

Comment: correct about p.date vs c.date - query must SELECT (every day of interest in calendar). Re: craziness - that started long before this drive was underway ;)